# Retrieve host name in Django behind a load balancer (ELB)

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I've been cracking my head on this for 2 days and can't get out of it... I have a class-based view where I need to use the full host name (skipping reasons here, just trust me), my code works fine until I deploy to an EC2 instance sitting behind an ELB.

Tried several approaches with no success so far, here's what I tried:

- basic CBV injection in `get_context_data`

  ```
  context['host_name'] = self.request.get_host()
  ```

  as [django docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host), this will fail if behind multi proxies and suggest to implement a middleware for it
- middleware, enabling the class exactly as stated in django docs, works fine on local but nothing happens on AWS
- using socket, hence in `get_context_data` doing something like:

  ```
  import socket
  context['host_name'] = socket.gethostname()
  ```

  this fails even on localhost, retrieving the name of the machine set by the operating system

my last resource is to hard code it in my settings, it would work but I'm not a big fan of it. any other clever ideas?

Comment: Does `socket.gethostname()` work from the command line ?  I wonder if it's OS level thing or more of Python/Django thing.

Comment: yeah, it basically returns the same content of `$(hostname)` run from the shell, which obviously does not make sense for a linux machine behind an ELB

Comment: What returns `$(hostname)` ? The command line or Django ?

Comment: as I said above, the output of `socket.gethostname()` in django is the same of `hostname` run from the shell, which is meaningless for an ec2 instance behind an elb